# Troubles with a degenerate conics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, conic-sections

I'm studying the following conics with respect upon a parameter $t$ (real).

$$2tx^2 + 2txy + 4y + 1 = 0$$

For those kinds of problems I have always followed this Wikipedia page, which I find the most clear among all the notes and websistes I have been searching though, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections

Yet There is something I cannot catch. So the matrix invariants in this case are

$$\text{det} \begin{pmatrix} 2t & t & 0 \\ t & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = -t(t+8)$$

Thence I get a degenerate conics if $t = 0$ or $t = -8$. So far so good.

The second invariant is

$$\text{det} \begin{pmatrix} 2t & t \\ t & 0 \end{pmatrix} = -t^2$$

Which is always negative for every real $t$, and it's zero for $t =0$

Now I am interested in the degenerate cases, but when I am going to study the $t = 0$ case I get stuck.

If $t = 0$ the conics is degenerate, and also the determinant of the second matrix is zero which means it's a pair of parallel lines. If I plot the resultin equation for $t = 0$ I simply get $4y + 1 = 0$ which I expect to be ONE single line.

However, suppose they are two parallel lines. Next step tells me that those lines are distinct, coincident or imaginary respectively if $D^2 + E^2$ is greater, equal or less than $4 (A+C) F$.

Here $D = 0$ and $E = 4$.
$A + C = 0$ hence I get $16 > 0$, which means two parallel distinct lines.

I am stuck over this for I cannot get where those two lines are.

Comment: I read the classification. Maybe it did not consider the case A=B=C=0, where the conic degraded into a line(degree 1) or degree 0. Your equation should be degree 2 to apply this classification.

Comment: @AbelWong You're so right, $A = B = C = 0$ is a sort of "trivial case". I did not pay attention to that simple caveat. Perhaps they really considered only the non trivial case... Thank you!

Comment: The asymptotes are $(x+2/t)(y+x-2/t)=0.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coming from a background of projective geometry, I would look at the homogeneous version of the equation:

$$2tx^2 + 2txy + 4yz + 1z^2 = 0$$

Then for $t=0$ you get

$$(4y + z)z = 0$$

So apart from the line $4y+z=0$ which is the $y=-\frac14$ line in non-homogeneous notation, there is also a line $z=0$ which is the line at infinity of the projective plane.

Would these two lines be considered parallel? Well, in projective geometry two lines are parallel if their point of intersection is on the line at infinity, i.e. has $z=0$. This is true for the intersection of the line at infinity with *any* finite line. So the line at infinity could be called parallel to all finite lines (which suddenly makes parallelism a non-transitive property so this might be a contentious interpretation).

Without resorting to projective geometry you don't get a handle on that second line. You would only have the one finite line, with multiplicity one and no second line that could be considered parallel or identical.